# dual processors with gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am very new to Gazebo. I am planning to buy a system (workstation) with the following specs for specifically using Gazebo related simulations:

Processor: Intel® Xeon® Processor E5504

Motherboard: X8DAL-i from Super Micro.

RAM 3GB (DDR3)

The board supports two processors but I am buying one only. Could you please guide is this a good machine for Gazebo related simulations with real time communications with any general purpose robot (say turtlebot etc.)? Also, does Gazebo supports two processors at the same time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5559/dual-processors-with-gazebo?/) by [mudassar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/638/mudassar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I haven't seen any (official or recent) guidelines that discuss what you can or can't run gazebo on.. The [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/installation__requirements.html) has the statement below that many have echoed before:

> Depending on what kind of environment
> and robots you're simulating, Gazebo
> can be computationally intensive. The
> exact CPU requirements will depend on
> how you use Gazebo, but in general we
> recommend that you err on the side of
> having a more powerful CPU.

Gazebo can be run on a single processor machine.. but be warned, expect laggy performance.. especially if you have complex objects in the environment. Most people would probably agree that at least 2 processors would be desirable, and 3 gigs of RAM would be workable. Also, Gazebo is decoupled into gzserver and gzclient.. but the operating system manages how these processes access your computer's resources.

Don't forget that you have to leave "space" for your control code to run, and if you process camera data or pointcloud data.

Finally, the graphics card is an important piece of hardware to consider as well. In the old days, Nvidia cards were better supported, and more people appeared to use those, but I've run Gazebo 1.8 on virtual graphics cards and I have been content.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0